# why can't my program convert a list of integars to text (string)?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, integer

I want to convert a list of integars (after picking up the prime numbers) to text ,one str (not a list of strings). How it can be acheived in a effective way as when i run the program it displays nothing not even 'error'
Btw the program is supposed to display: "11-19"

***this is my code :***

```
v=[11,18,19]
n=3
def premier(v):   
        I=2
        valid=True
        while valid==True and  ( I<=(v/2) ) :
            if (v%I !=0) :
                I +=1              
            else:
                valide=False                
        return(valid)
def chaine(v,n):
    ch=""
    for i in range(n):
        if premier(v[i]):
            ch=ch+str(v[i])+"-"
    ch=ch[:len(ch)-1]
    return(ch)
print(chaine(v,n))
```

Comment: You have a typo that's causing an infinite loop: `valide=False` should be `valid=False` in your `while` loop. You're defining a new variable with what you're doing now so `valid` would never be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the first `else` statement of the function `premier`, which causes an infinite loop.

```
v=[11,18,19]
n=3
def premier(v):
        I=2
        valid=True
        while valid==True and  ( I<=(v/2) ) :
            if (v%I !=0) :
                I +=1
            else:
                valid=False
        return(valid)

def chaine(v,n):
    ch=""
    for i in range(n):
        if premier(v[i]):
            ch=ch+str(v[i])+"-"
    ch=ch[:len(ch)-1]
    return(ch)
print(chaine(v,n))
```

With this minor change, your code should work fine. Let me know if this works for you.